# Re-using values without declaring variables

Tags: rust

In Kotlin, I can re-use values so:

```
"127.0.0.1:135".let {
    connect(it) ?: System.err.println("Failed to connect to $it")
}
```

Is anything similar possible in Rust? To avoid using a temporary variable like this:

```
let text_address = "127.0.0.1:135";
TcpListener::bind(text_address).expect(format!("Failed to connect to {}", text_address));
```

Comment: `it` is still a variable, same with `$_` in Perl

Comment: If you want to reuse the binding (variable) name, you can wrap the temporary usage in a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html), `T.let` in Kotlin is a generic method-like function which runs a closure `(T) -> R` with the given value `T` passed as the first argument. From this perspective, it resembles a mapping operation from `T` to `R`. Under Kotlin's syntax though, it looks like a means of making a scoped variable with additional emphasis.

We could do the exact same thing in Rust, but it doesn't bring anything new to the table, nor makes the code cleaner (using `_let` because `let` is a keyword in Rust):

```
trait LetMap {
    fn _let<F, R>(self, mut f: F) -> R
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(Self) -> R,
    {
        f(self)
    }
}
impl<T> LetMap for T {}

// then...

"something"._let(|it| {
    println!("it = {}", it);
    "good"
});
```

When dealing with a single value, it is actually more idiomatic to just declare a variable. If you need to constrain the variable (and/or the value's lifetime) to a particular scope, just place it in a block:

```
let conn = {
    let text_address = "127.0.0.1:135";
    TcpListener::bind(text_address)?
};
```

There is also one more situation worth mentioning: Kotlin has an idiom for nullable values where `x?.let` is used to conditionally perform something when the value isn't null.

```
val value = ...

value?.let {
    ... // execute this block if not null
}
```

In Rust, an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) already provides a similar feature, either through pattern matching or the many available methods with conditional execution: `map`, `map_or_else`, `unwrap_or_else`, `and_then`, and more.

```
let value: Option<_> = get_opt();

// 1: pattern matching
if let Some(non_null_value) = value {
    // ...
}

// 2: functional methods
let new_opt_value: Option<_> = value.map(|non_null_value| {
    "a new value"
}).and_then(some_function_returning_opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar

```
{
    let text_address = "127.0.0.1:135";
    TcpListener::bind(text_address).expect(format!("Failed to connect to {}", text_address));
}
// now text_address is out of scope
```